# Java - How can I create a class that can process objects of Generics of a specific [restricted] type?

Tags: java, generics

How can I create a class that can process objects of Generics of a specific type?

For example, I have this class based on Generics:

```
interface TypeWithGetAndSetMethod<T> {
    void storeLocal(T arg1);
    T getLocal();
}

class RestrictedClassType<T> implements TypeWithGetAndSetMethod<T> {
    T local;
    public void storeLocal(T arg1) {
        local = arg1;
    }
    public T getLocal() {
        return local;
    }
}
```

A simple test succeeds:

```
void testRestrictedGenericsType() {
    RestrictedClassType<String> restrictedClassType = new RestrictedClassType<>();
    restrictedClassType.storeLocal( "String-1");
    System.out.println( "Restricted class: " + restrictedClassType.getLocal());
}
```

Now I would like to have a class than can process the above (generic) class. So I pass it to a processing class and the method can only accept generic classes implementing the interface.

The code I have so far is not compiling:

```
// Not compiling
class ProcessRestrictedGenericsType<T> {
    T localVar;
    public <S extends TypeWithGetAndSetMethod<T>> void procesTypeWithGetAndSetMethod(T arg) {
        this.localVar = arg;
    }
    public T getRestrictedType() {
        return localVar.getLocal();
    }
}
```

The test of that processing code has compiling code:

```
void testMethodWithRestrictedGenericType() {
    RestrictedClassType<String> restrictedClassType = new RestrictedClassType<>();
    restrictedClassType.storeLocal( "String-1");
    ProcessRestrictedGenericsType<TypeWithGetAndSetMethod> classRestrictedMethod = new ProcessRestrictedGenericsType<>();
    classRestrictedMethod.aMethodWithRestrictedGenericType( restrictedClassType);
    System.out.println( "The output is: " + classRestrictedMethod.getRestrictedType());
}
```

Can you help me creating the processing class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need both parameters, the value type and the wrapper type:

```
class ProcessRestrictedGenericsType<T, W extends TypeWithGetAndSetMethod<? extends Value>> {
    WlocalVar;
    public void procesTypeWithGetAndSetMethod(Warg) {
        this.localVar = arg;
    }
    public T getRestrictedType() {
        return localVar.getLocal();
    }
}
```

Then your test will work:

```
void testMethodWithRestrictedGenericType() {
    RestrictedClassType<String> restrictedClassType = new RestrictedClassType<>();
    restrictedClassType.storeLocal( "String-1");
    ProcessRestrictedGenericsType<String, TypeWithGetAndSetMethod<String>> classRestrictedMethod = new ProcessRestrictedGenericsType<>();
    classRestrictedMethod.procesTypeWithGetAndSetMethod(restrictedClassType);
    System.out.println( "The output is: " + classRestrictedMethod.getRestrictedType());
}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you stuck to Java code conventions and used single letters for generic type arguments.  Making generic types look like class names is just confusing.

Comment: @VGR I would say this convention has became obsolete since we have proper IDEs which highlight class types and parameter types differently.

Comment: And I would disagree.  Writing hard-to-read code is not more acceptable because "an IDE can handle it."

Comment: @VGR In this case I agree that it's easier to read with single-letter names because the whole class fits on a screen, but in case of, say, large classes and classes with more than two type parameters it's arguable. Regular type names (akin to class names) can provide deeper semantics, and make it actually easier to understand what's going on. The Google's convention, for example, allows for both single-letter names and class-like names ending with `T`, so I would say a significant group of Java professionals have a similar point.